# XSLT: position() and last() not returning expected result

Tags: xslt

I would like to get the position of each `svg:use[@href='#electron']` when it's matched. I'm expecting to have the position among other elements of the same match, but instead I'm getting numbers I don't understand. How should I use `position()` and `last()` to get expected figures ?

```
<!-- Add node "animateTransform" -->
<xsl:template match="svg:use[@href='#electron']">
    <!-- Copy the element -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- And everything inside it -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">val</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 0 0" to="0 0 0" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>/<xsl:value-of select="last()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, including input, your XSLT, and the expected result - see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position()` and `last()` functions return the position relative to the current node-set.

The node-set is, however, not determined by the `match` attribute; this is just a filter which determines which template shall be applied.

The problem lies in the part which does select the nodes on which to apply templates, e.g. the `apply-templates` which ends up having the `svg:use` matches.

Try to use this at that location:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="svg:use[@href='#electron']"/>
```

You'll then get the expected position.

Alternatively you can change your check for the last item, for instance like this:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::svg:use[@href='#electron'])">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">val</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: The alternative works perfect. But the given `apply-templates` still gives me the same unexpected `position` and `last` and removes the content of `<use>`.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. But you haven't really explained what your expectation is, or why, so it's hard to tell precisely which stick you have got the wrong end of.